# sum many user select of array to show the total (angular)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

In my project, in `summary.component.ts` I've two array one dependent on the other:

```
state: State[]
city: City[]
selection: number[] = number
```

where class **state.ts**:

```
id: number
name: string
```

and class **city.ts**

```
id: number
name: string
score: number
state: State
```

In DB i have this situation:

```
STATE
--------------
id | name     |
--------------
 1 | USA      |
--------------
 2 | UK       |
--------------
 3 | Italy    |
--------------

CITY
-----------------------------------
id | name       | score | state_id |
-----------------------------------
1  | New York   | 8     | 1        |
-----------------------------------
2  | Boston     | 6     | 1        |
-----------------------------------
3  | Miami      | 4     | 1        |
-----------------------------------
4  | London     | 9     | 2        |
-----------------------------------
5  | Manchester | 8     | 2        |
-----------------------------------
6  | Liverpool  | 9     | 2        |
-----------------------------------
7  | Rome       | 11    | 3        |
-----------------------------------
8  | Florence   | 10    | 3        |
-----------------------------------
9  | Turin      | 7     | 3        |
-----------------------------------
```

In the HTML page (`summary.component.html`) I divided the select with the `slice`:

```html
            <div name="state">
              <div *ngFor="let st of state | slice:0:1;">
                {{ st.state }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <select [(ngModel)]="selection[0]" name="city0" id="id0">
              <option [ngValue]="cityname.id" *ngFor="let ci of city | slice:0:3; index as i">
                {{ ci.name }} <p>|</p>
                {{ ci.score }}
              </option>
            </select>
            
            <div name="state">
              <div *ngFor="let st of state | slice:1:2;">
                {{ st.state }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <select [(ngModel)]="selection[1]" name="city1" id="id1">
              <option [ngValue]="cityname.id" *ngFor="let ci of city | slice:3:6; index as i">
                {{ ci.name }} <p>|</p>
                {{ ci.score }}
              </option>
            </select>
            
            <div name="state">
              <div *ngFor="let st of state | slice:2:3;">
                {{ st.state }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <select [(ngModel)]="selection[2]" name="city2" id="id2">
              <option [ngValue]="cityname.id" *ngFor="let ci of city | slice:6:9; index as i">
                {{ ci.name }} <p>|</p>
                {{ ci.score }}
              </option>
            </select>
```

How can I manage the sum of the scores chosen by the user based on the selections that are made in the array?
i was thinking about an `outputTotal` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all using `slice` pipe the way you did is a bad design (imagine what happens if your data source changes and you have to go and update all slice indexes). You can easily get rid of `slice` by using nested `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` like:

```html
<div name="state" *ngFor="let st of state">
   <div>
  {{ st.state }}
   </div>
   <select [(ngModel)]="selection">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let ci of city; index as i">
  <option *ngIf="ci.state_id === st.id" [ngValue]="cityname.id">
  {{ ci.name }} 
  <p>|</p>
  {{ ci.score }}
  </option>
   </ng-container>
   </select>
</div>
```

By doing this you will have a single array of selections so you can calculate total output as:

```
const totalOutput = city.filter(c => selection.includes(c.id)).reduce((a,c) => a + c.score, 0);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I don't know why when I go to choose a select, it is not saved and disappears if I go to choose another on another state